# How to install Huawei Mobile broadband EC306?

Tags: modem

How to install **Huawei Mobile Broadband EC 306 EVDO RevB**  in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit ?

Best Regards

---

*Excuses me for my bad english*

When I connect the modem on ubuntu, it fails to mount system and furthermore it is not recognized as a CD-ROM.

I is not installed Windows on my computer, but I try to open the modem under Windows on a PC friend, There is no script file called "Linux", but only Windows.

lsusb :

```
serviteur@creation:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 15d9:0a4c Trust International B.V. USB+PS/2 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
```

dmesg

```
Q: 0 ANSI: 2
[16619.060771] sr1: scsi-1 drive
[16619.060955] sr 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[16619.061099] sr 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
[16619.061358] sd 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[16619.063654] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[16634.224923] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 6
[16638.468041] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
[16638.586210] option 1-6:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[16638.586316] usb 1-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[16638.586435] option 1-6:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[16638.586517] usb 1-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[16638.586607] option 1-6:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[16638.586676] usb 1-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[16638.586752] option 1-6:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[16638.586828] usb 1-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[16638.586929] option 1-6:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[16638.586997] usb 1-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[16638.587114] option 1-6:1.5: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[16638.587187] usb 1-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB5
[16638.646686] option1 ttyUSB5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB5
[16638.646706] option 1-6:1.5: device disconnected
[16638.660755] scsi15 : usb-storage 1-6:1.5
[16638.663284] option1 ttyUSB4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB4
[16638.663301] option 1-6:1.4: device disconnected
[16638.689043] scsi16 : usb-storage 1-6:1.4
```

Answer (score 3):

Connect the dongle/modem/adapter/whatever-you-like-calling-it and browse through the files on the onboard storage (often shown as a CD-ROM in devices). Do you see any script-file called 'linux'? Select it and right-click. Under 'properties', check 'execute'.

Now, open the file and click on 'run in terminal'.

Share the results.

UPDATE:
Sometimes, the modem storage media fails to mount on Ubuntu systems. Try opening it on Windows (for which they're made for! :-( ). Now, copy all files on it to your Ubuntu system and do as said earlier.

UPDATE2:
[OPTION 1]
The device storage is shown as a flash drive on your system.

Execute the following command in the terminal (all in one line):

```
echo 'SUBSYSTEM == "usb", SYSFS {idProduct} == " 1506 ", SYSFS {idVendor} ==" 12d1 ", RUN + = "/ lib / udev / modem-modeswitch - vendor 0x 12d1 - Product 0x 1506 - type option-zerocd "'| sudo tee / etc/udev/rules.d/45-huawei1550.rules
```

After the command file `45-huawei1550.rules` appears in the directory `/etc/udev/rules.d/`  , from which the OS will load the drivers when the modem is connected next time.

Now, disconnect the modem and reboot. Plug the modem. Open `network connections` and set-up the connection according to your location & ISP.

[OPTION 2]:
a. To install the Linux Driver tool only:
Run the following command in the installation directory:

```
    `./install $PATH`        (The "PATH" is where the driver directory is)
```

And then copy `usbmod` & `startMobilePartner` files to `/bin/`

Copy `45-Huawei-Datacard.rules` file to `/etc/dev/rules.d/`

Restart the system and connect modem again.

Good luck.

Comment: Excuses me for my bad english 



When I connect the modem on ubuntu, it fails to mount system and furthermore it is not recognized as a CD-ROM.

I is not installed Windows on my computer, but I try to open the modem under Windows on a PC friend, There is no script file called "Linux", but only Windows.

Comment: Just in case the command doesn't work as intended, take note of any extra spaces I might have put.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

After extracted linuxdriver.gz file go into the driver directory and open in terminal.
Run following commands

```
cd /path-to-the-directory-where-you-extracted
sudo chmod 777 install
sudo ./install
```

Answer (score 0):

I run the following command in the terminal:

```
servant @ creation: ~ $ echo 'SUBSYSTEM == "usb", SYSFS {idProduct} == "1506" SYSFS {idVendor} == "12D1", RUN + = "/ lib / udev / modem-modeswitch - vendor 0x 12D1 - Product 0x 1506 - type option-zerocd "'| sudo tee / etc/udev/rules.d/45-huawei1550.rules

[sudo] password for servant

tee: /: is a directory

tee: etc/udev/rules.d/45-huawei1550.rules: No such file or such

SUBSYSTEM == "usb", SYSFS {idProduct} == "1506" SYSFS {idVendor} == "12D1", RUN + = "/ lib / udev / modem-modeswitch - vendor 12D1 0x - 0x 1506 Product - type option -zerocd "

servant @ creation: ~ $

45 huawei1550.rules file does not appear in the directory / etc / udev / rules.d /
```

the modem is still not up.

I downloaded the driver on this link: http://www.huaweidevice.com/tcpsdownload/downLoadCenter?category=&flay=software&downloadID=NDAzMjM =

In the Linux driver, there is no file-45 Huawei Datacard.rules but
File Huawei-10-10-Datacard.rules and Huawei Datacard-and-old.rules also 49Huwaei

I installed the driver:

```
serviteur@creation:~$ cd /home/serviteur/driver

serviteur@creation:~/driver$ sudo ./install

INSTALL_PATH is not set ,auto install

CURRENT PATH=/home/serviteur/driver

INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/Mobile_Partner

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver

Usage: modinfo [-0][-F field][-k kernelversion][-b basedir]  module...

 Prints out the information about one or more module(s).

 If a fieldname is given, just print out that field (or nothing if not found).

 Otherwise, print all information out in a readable form

 If -0 is given, separate with nul, not newline.

 If -b is given, use an image of the module tree.

ERROR: Removing 'cdc_ether': No such file or directory

ERROR: Removing 'usbnet': No such file or directory

ERROR: Removing 'hw_cdc_driver': No such file or directory

make -C src/ clean

make[1]: entrant dans le répertoire « /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src »

rm -rf *.o *.ko *~ core* .dep* .*.d .*.cmd *.mod.c *.a *.s .*.flags .tmp_versions Module.symvers Modules.symvers *.order

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "clean" "/lib/modules/3.2.0-23-lowlatency/build/include/linux/usb"

rmmod -f hw_cdc_driver

ERROR: Removing 'hw_cdc_driver': No such file or directory

make[1]: *** [clean] Erreur 1

make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src »

make: *** [clean] Erreur 2

make -C src/ modules

make[1]: entrant dans le répertoire « /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src »

#/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "modules" "/lib/modules/3.2.0-23-lowlatency/build/include/linux/usb"

make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-23-lowlatency/build SUBDIRS=/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src modules

make[2]: entrant dans le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23-lowlatency »

  CC [M]  /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.o

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘hw_change_mtu’:

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:898:2: attention : format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t’ [-Wformat]

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘rx_tlp_parse’:

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:1084:7: attention : ISO C89 interdit les mélanges de déclarations et de code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘tx_complete’:

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:1662:5: attention : format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t’ [-Wformat]

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘cdc_ncm_config’:

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:2035:24: attention : il manque un transtypage pour comparer des types distincts de pointeur [enabled by default]

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:2036:3: attention : il manque un transtypage pour comparer des types distincts de pointeur [enabled by default]

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:2036:3: attention : il manque un transtypage pour comparer des types distincts de pointeur [enabled by default]

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:2040:21: attention : il manque un transtypage pour comparer des types distincts de pointeur [enabled by default]

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:2056:3: attention : format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘hw_cdc_probe’:

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:3021:26: attention : ‘ctx’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:2794:21: note: ‘ctx’ was declared here

  Building modules, stage 2.

  MODPOST 1 modules

  CC      /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.mod.o

  LD [M]  /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.ko

make[2]: quittant le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23-lowlatency »

strip --strip-debug hw_cdc_driver.o

make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src »

make -C src/ install

make[1]: entrant dans le répertoire « /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src »

#install -m 744 -c hw_cdc_driver.o /lib/modules/3.2.0-23-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/usb/net

#depmod -a

#modprobe hw_cdc_driver

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "install"

modprobe hw_cdc_driver

WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist, it will be ignored in a future release.

make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src »



The Linux NDIS driver is installed successfully.

have usb_modeswitch rules to HUAWEI DataCard: COUNT=1

RULESFILE =/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules

COUNT_START=1

COUNT_END=0

AUTORUNPATH=/home/serviteur/.kde/share/autostart

AUTORUNPATH=/home/serviteur/.kde/Autostart

AUTORUNPATH=/home/serviteur/.config/autostart

ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc3.d

«/etc/rc3.d/S99runhwactivator» -> «/etc/init.d/runhwactivator»

«/etc/rc3.d/K10runhwactivator» -> «/etc/init.d/runhwactivator»

ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc2.d

«/etc/rc2.d/S99runhwactivator» -> «/etc/init.d/runhwactivator»

«/etc/rc2.d/K10runhwactivator» -> «/etc/init.d/runhwactivator»

ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc4.d

«/etc/rc4.d/S99runhwactivator» -> «/etc/init.d/runhwactivator»

«/etc/rc4.d/K10runhwactivator» -> «/etc/init.d/runhwactivator»

ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc5.d

«/etc/rc5.d/S99runhwactivator» -> «/etc/init.d/runhwactivator»

«/etc/rc5.d/K10runhwactivator» -> «/etc/init.d/runhwactivator»

serviteur@creation:~/driver$
```

README.TXT

```
1.Installation

  a. To install the Linux Driver tool only:

     call the following command in the installation directory:

        ./install $PATH         (The parameter "PATH" is where the driver directory is)

     And the can copy usbmod file to /sbin/

                 copy startMobilePartner file to /sbin/

                 copy 10-Huawei-Datacard.rules file to /etc/udev/rules.d/

                 register the auto run settengs into the current system.

     To make the settings applied, you must restart the system.

  b. To integrated the Linux Driver tool into the third dashboard application:

     call "install norestart" in the installation tool of the third dashboard application. 

     This call scheme will disable the restarting function in the tool installation.

     And after the third dashboard application installed, its installation tool must restart the current system.



 2. To inquire about the version of the Linux Driver tool,

    call HWActivator --version.



 3. The current version is : Linux Driver 4.19.07.00


HWActivator Linux Driver 4.19.07.00
```