# Huawei EC306 (Tata Photon Max) is not working on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, usb-modem, huawei

I've just installed Huawei EC306 dongle in Ubuntu 13.10 as described in user manual and provided software in Data Card.

I executed script: `sudo ./install_linux` from application provided in Dongle memory

Above script installs application `MobilePartner` successfully.

After restarting system, MobilePartner automatically appers on screen when Data card plugs.

But the problem is it does not detects device and triggers a message **"Please insert the device to make a connection"**

I also tried this solution but this also does not works!
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1814583

**`lsusb` output is:**

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:58c1 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21bc Broadcom Corp. BCM2070 Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 045e:0783 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**See this screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Does the device lists when you click on network connections panel as Mobile broadband or any similar?? If it does; it will allow you to create a mobile dial-up... if not just try to modprobe the device & this tutorial may help you to do it to your device > http://www.geeklk.com/2013/02/prolink-phs300-dongle-on-ubuntu

Comment: Yes, device is listed in Network Connection System drop down menu. But when I clicks on that it try to connects again and again.

Comment: Disconnect your device, give you system a reboot & wait until it boots up, then plug the device and try to check network connections by creating a dial-up. If that didn't work, try modprobe'ing your device using the link I've gave you. And make sure you select the right ID when modprobe'ing.

Comment: I did all that you suggested. But still not found any solution... :(

Comment: I also found a question similar to the same device.. may be this helps > http://askubuntu.com/questions/205139/how-to-install-huawei-mobile-broadband-ec306

Comment: Provided application with Data card I also installed in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and it works well there. Just when Photon Max application appears first time then asks for Photon number but don't asks in Ubuntu 13.10. Can I put Photon number in any configuration file?

Comment: So, no one has idea about this.